# I am trying to perform the tranpose function but can not get it

Tags: c++

I have problems with the final void function i tried to assingn it to a variable i declared int l but i cant since the functions return type is void and for some reason i do get the same result for both the row and column sum and toal sum and i am confused about what should i do or how to calculate row or column seperately here is the question

Write a menu driven C++ program to do following operation on two dimensional array A of size m x n. You should use user-defined functions which accept 2-D array A, and its size m and n as arguments. The options are:

To input elements into matrix of size m x n
To display elements of matrix of size m x n
Sum of all elements of matrix of size m x n
To display row-wise sum of matrix of size m x n
To display column-wise sum of matrix of size m x n
To create transpose of matrix B of size n x n

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void showcases();

void input_element(int A[][20], int& m, int& n);

void display_matrix(int A[][20], int& m, int& n);

int sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n);

int row_sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n);

int col_sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n);

void transp(int A[][20], int B[][20], int& m, int& n);

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, choice = 0, A[10][20], B[10][20], n = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, l = 0;

    for (int k = 0; choice <= 6; k++)
    {
        showcases();
        x = sum(A, a, b);
        y = row_sum(A, a, b);
        z = col_sum(A, a, b);

        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1) {
            input_element(A, a, b);
        }

        if (choice == 2) {
            display_matrix(A, a, b);
        }

        if (choice == 3) {
            cout << "The sum of the matrix elements is " << x << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 4) {
            cout << "The sum of the matrix rows is " << y << endl;

        }

        if (choice == 5) {
            cout << "The sum of the matrix columns is " << z << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 6) {
            transp(A, B, a, b);
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (choice >= 7 || choice <= 0) {
            cout << "Your choice is invalid" << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void input_element(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    int row, col;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> m;

    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int r = 0; r < m; r++)
        for (int colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the elements for the array: ";
            cin >> A[r][colum];
        }
}

void display_matrix(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{

    for (int r = 0; r < m; r++)
        for (int colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
        {
            cout << "Entered element is " << ": ";
            cout << A[r][colum];
            cout << endl;
        }
}

int sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    int s = 0, r, colum;
    for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        for (colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
        {
            s += A[r][colum];
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int row_sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    int r_s = 0, r, colum;
    for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        for (colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
        {
            r_s += A[r][colum];
        }
    }
    return r_s;
}

int col_sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    int col_s(0), colum, r;
    for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        for (colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
        {
            col_s += A[colum][r];
        }
    }
    return col_s;
}

void transp(int A[][20], int B[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    int r, colum;
    for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        for (colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
            B[r][colum] = A[colum][r];
    }
    for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        for (colum = 0; colum < n; colum++)
            cout << B[r][colum];
    }
    return;
}

void showcases()
{
    cout << "Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. input elements" << endl;
    cout << "2. Display matrix" << endl;
    cout << "3. Sum of matrix elements" << endl;
    cout << "4. Sum of matrix rows" << endl;
    cout << "5. Sum of matrix elements" << endl;
    cout << "6. The transpose of elements" << endl;
    cout << "7. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Choose among the options above: ";
}
```

I need the row and column sum to be different and im trying to fix the transpose part

Comment: You do not need the return type in a function call. You do need a semicolon. `l =void transp( A,  B,  m,  n)` should be `l = transp( A,  B,  m,  n);` Thinking a bit more, you need a non-`void` return type if you intend to return something. It looks like all of the work is being done on `B`, so there is no need to return anything.

Comment: Suggestion: Test stuff in isolation.Make a little program that does nothing but call `transp` a few dozen different ways to make sure it is correct without all of the noise from the rest of the program. When it works correctly, then add it to the larger program.

Comment: Also note that there is not much point to transposing A into B before getting A from the user.

Comment: @user4581301 i rewrite the code and update it but i yet get some random number after i input the elements and then select 6. -85689076. can you help me out. i am a newbie

Comment: @user4581301 can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// protype
void showcases();
void accept(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b);
void outputs(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b);
int sum(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b);
void row_sum(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b);
void col_sum(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b);
void transposed(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b);

int main()
{
    // variable declaration
    int a = 0, b = 0, choice = 0, A[10][20], n = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    // For loop execution
    for (int k = 0; choice <= 6; k++)
    {
        x = sum(A, a, b);

        showcases();
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;

        if (choice == 1) {
            accept(A, a, b);
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 2) {
            outputs(A, a, b);
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

        }

        if (choice == 3) {
            cout << "The sum of the matrix elements is " << x << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

        }

        if (choice == 4) {
            col_sum(A, a, b);
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 5) {
            row_sum(A, a, b);
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 6) {
            cout << "Elements of matrix after transpose are: " << endl;
            transposed(A, a, b);
            cout << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice >= 7 || choice <= 0) {
            cout << "Your choice is invalid" << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

// To input the elements 
void accept(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b)
{
    cout << "Enter  number of rows for matrix: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter number of columns for matrix: ";
    cin >> b;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
// to keep a track of your position in array

            cout << "Enter elements of matrix " << "[" << i << "]" << " [" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> Array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

// TO output the elements 
void outputs(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            cout << Array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// To find the total sum 
int sum(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b)
{
    int s = 0, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            s += Array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return s;
}

// To find the row sum
//you only need to find the row sum
void row_sum(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b)
{
    int row_s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            row_s += Array[i][j];
        }
        cout << "sum of" << i + 1 << " Row is " << row_s;
        row_s = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return;
}


// To find the column sum 
//Same you were suming up all the elements
void col_sum(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b)
{
    int col_s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            col_s += Array[j][i];
        }
        cout << "sum of" << i + 1 << " column is " << col_s;
        col_s = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return;
}

// To transpose (To change the elements of rows and columns) the matrix 
// you do not need to call b to store A
void transposed(int Array[][20], int& a, int& b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            cout << Array[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return;
}

// To display (To showcase) the available choiced 
void showcases()
{
    cout << "Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. input elements" << endl;
    cout << "2. Display matrix" << endl;
    cout << "3. Sum of matrix elements" << endl;
    cout << "4. Sum of matrix rows" << endl;
    cout << "5. Sum of matrix elements" << endl;
    cout << "6. The transpose of elements" << endl;
    cout << "7. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Choose among the options above: ";
}
```